# Drawing a box around results of php - syntax

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a page of results from a mysql database using php, encasing each line of results (which contains an image and some other lines of detail) in a box.

Currently, page.php gets the data from the db, and uses result.inc to format the data into rows of information three cells per row.

```
Address1   Picture    Comment
Address2   Picture2   Comment2
etc.
```

I would like to encase each row in pretty box (or even just a box). This produces one empty (but bordered) box before the table, then the table as normal.

How to close off the box with the results inside?

```
<style>
    p {
        outline-style: solid;
        outline-width: 5px;
    }
</style>

for($i=1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    print("<p>");
    print("<TR>");
    include("includes/result.inc");
    print("</TR>");
    print("</p>");
}
```

Comment: You can't insert `tr` tags directly inside a `p` tag, they need to be wrapped with a full `table` markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put p-tags between table rows. Instead, style the table rows themselves:

```
<style>
    tr {
        outline-style: solid;
        outline-width: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

And the php:

```
for($i=1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    print("<TR>");
    include("includes/result.inc");
    print("</TR>");
}
```